# Converting JSON to Array with Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I use this function I get the following result from my realtime database. It looks like a json object.
How can I turn that to an array or retrieve the string userName? snapshot.userName is not working.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

   exports.Push = functions.database.ref('/placeID/{pushId}/')
   .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
 
      console.log(snapshot)    
   })
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A Realtime Database [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database.datasnapshot) object is a container that *contains* your data. To get the data it contains, you need to retrieve its value using the `val()` method:

```js
console.log(snapshot.val());
```

To get the `userName` from your data, you can use either:

```js
console.log(snapshot.val().userName)
// note: if "userName" is missing, this will log `undefined`
```

or

```js
// more useful with large snapshots
console.log(snapshot.child("userName").val())
// note: if "userName" is missing, this will log `null`
```

See following link for more info about the `DataSnapshot` object and available methods/properties:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database.datasnapshot

**Added note:** The `DataSnapshot` class overrides the [`toJSON()`](https://firebase.google.com/static/docs/reference/functions/providers_database.datasnapshot#tojson) method, this is why when you log it, you saw the data it contained rather than the DataSnapshot's own methods/properties.

Comment: I already did that my description above was wrong. I tried snapshot.userName and get undefined as result

Comment: Please check out my edited answer and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you for the updated code. The result is the same as on my first post.

Comment: Does `snapshot.val().userName` return the username?

Comment: BTW Travis, only you will get notifications about comments on your own answer, to notify OP that you are responding to them you need to tag them using @submariner.

Comment: If I try console.log(snapshot.val().userName) I get undefined. But userName is not missing as you can see the screenshot above. And also the second code of you says null. I added the structure of my realtime database to my first post.

Comment: It looks like I kinda did it. But why can I not use for example this as ref: ('/placeID/{autoid1}/{autoId2}/') ?

Answer (score 0):

`snapshot` is a reference to a Firestore **document**. In order to get the data contained in a document `doc` you need to call `doc.data()`. So in your case it would be `doc.data().userName`.

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#web-version-9_1) for some examples.

Comment: I tried console.log(doc.data().userName) but it says doc is not defined. I looked at the url which u send but did not understand any word from that.

Comment: try `console.log(snapshot.val().userName)`

Comment: this gives me undefined as an answer